# Is there any standard to burn these tokens?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721, solidity-0.8.x, erc

I am learning Solidity .
Currrently I am learning about ERC token standards . I want to write a smart contract in which it is possible for "msg.sender" who is calling the mint() function to be able to burn those tokens which he is minting for "to" . Is there any ERC standard to achieve this functionality ?

Suppose Bob is the owner of contract , Henry is calling the mint function and minting the tokens to address of Alice . I want Henry to be able to burn those tokens that he minted to the address of Alice .

Also , by default who except the token owner has authority to burn his tokens ? In the above example , who except Alice ( owner of tokens ) can burn the tokens ( without being the owner of the token ) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be a standard, since it disrupts the core feature of blockchain, ie, the removal of a central authority. If you give that right to anyone other than the token owner, it will be a centralized system like a bank that controls your money.

ALthough, you can write your own code and change the standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

Usually burning tokens are done by sending them to [null address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), 0x00000...

have an additional hash map(address -> tokenIndex) on top of ERC standard and check if the address can burn a particular token.

Answer (score 0):

The standard of burning Tokens is just transferring the tokens to the 0x00 address

Assuming that you are using Openzeppelin contracts:

There isn't anyone who can burn tokens but the owner unless the owner has added an extra EOA or Contract as operator of your tokens;

Ie. When you sell your nfts in Opensea, before listing you set Opensea's Seaport Marketplace contract as operator of your tokens; then if someone buys your nft, Seaport can transfer the token from your wallet to someone else's wallet after the buyer pays.

being said this:

There are 2 ways where Wallet A (Henry) can burn the tokens of Wallet B (Alice)

1. Alice calls approveForAll() and adds the operator flag to Henry, then Henry can call the burn() function
2. You modify the contract to allow henry burn alice's tokens:

   2.1.- on smartcontract level, remove the ownership requirement to burn tokens

   2.2.- add some security steps to control who can burn or not

**Note regarding number 2.- (Its unsafe and risky and I don't recommend it)**

If you where to do it this way, you need to take security measures and protect your burn function; You might want to implement Ownable.sol and add a modifier to your function "only owner" so no-one but the deployer of the contract can call the burn function; you can also implement Access control contract to control who can burn